# Ubuntu Wordpress installation: error 500 on every plugin activation

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, ubuntu, lamp

I have a Ubuntu 20.04 VPS with LAMP and Wordpress 5.7 installed.
Everytime that I try to activate a plugin, the website goes in error 500.
I want to understand why.

Actually to solve the issue I have to copy Wordpress core files in the main directory of my website, and I have to do this every time I want to activate a plugin...

I also tried to edit the PHP memory limit (now at 3000M) and then increase this limit also in the wp-config file, but with no success.

Answer (score 0):

The error 500 means that there has been an error in the server side. Most probably you won't be able to fix it yourself.

My suggestion is to export the site using All-In-One plugin https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/

Reinstall wordpress from scratch and import the site back.

Comment: I now that, is whats I wrote in my question.
What's happening:

> I upload a plugin and then activate it 
> After the activation, I can see that the plugin is active from the Plugins page
> Now the website is in error 500
> I upload all Wordpress core files again
> Website is working

And this happens every time

Comment: @Giovanni as I said, you need to reinstall wordpress again. Your current installation is broken and it will keep happening unless you destroy it and reinstall it again. You also need to restore the database, since most probably the problem comes from there.

Comment: I reinstalled it 4 times